# Where to store connection string for classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

In ASP.NET i can store connection string in the web.config, like wise i need to store connection string or some configuration value in some file for classic ASP.

How can i do this? In order to achieve this do i need to use XML File and store the connection string in this?

What is the best practice???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `globa.asa` to set a value in the application object.

Comment: That works within that one app, but it wouldn't work across the enterprise (assuming there are multiple apps)

Comment: Configuration is normally on a per-app basis (including asp.net web.config). Security wise it is also best practice to use different db user accounts per app.

Comment: And if each of my client has a connection string? Each one of them accessing an Azure SQL database.

Answer (score 5):

You can make an ASP file that contains the connection string as a string variable, along with any other configuration information, then include it in files that connect to the database.

Comment: This should be a .inc file or .asp file?

Comment: make it an .asp file. In the distant past I saw a server configured in such a way that .inc files were not interpreted by the asp runtime, resulting in the server downloading the source of the .inc file. That would be vastly less likely to happen with an .asp file.

Comment: @Nimesh and @Paul, as Joost suggest in his answer, using `global.asa` seems the better solution.. It is accessible by all pages without the need to include anything...

Answer (score 2):

A quote I picked up recently...

> Don't do something silly like store
>   the secret in a file that's sitting in
>   a virtual directory on a Web server
>   (web.config comes to mind). Web
>   servers have been known to
>   accidentally allow files to be
>   downloaded because of bugs. For
>   example, connection strings in classic
>   ASP pages could be stolen in the past
>   by pointing a Web browser to
>   '**page.asp::$DATA**' instead of
>   page.asp. This fooled IIS into
>   thinking that the request was for a
>   static file because .asp::$DATA
>   wouldn't match anything in its script
>   map. But the suffix ::$DATA has
>   special meaning to the operating
>   system: It indicates the default NTFS
>   stream for the file, which is what you
>   get when you read the contents of the
>   file normally. In other words, asking
>   the file system for page.aspx::$DATA
>   is the same as asking it for the
>   contents of page.aspx. Thus IIS would
>   serve up the source of the ASP page
>   instead of interpreting it as a
>   script. There have been lots of
>   shenanigans like this over the years,
>   but most folks would agree that you're
>   better off storing sensitive files
>   outside of any virtual directory on a
>   Web server. Even better, keep
>   sensitive files on a different
>   partition then where your virtual
>   directories reside.